# iOS Camera Preview Method on entry - Overlay Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, overlay, preview

how can I know when the camera preview is showed after the picture is taken? I want this because I'm using an overlay and when the app goes to the camera preview, the bottom bar gets smaller and so my overlay doesn't cover all the screen, all that I want is to resize this overlay when the camera preview is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using a translation for down on "camerapicker.transform" property, so now taken picture would be at the same position as while taking the photo, so the overlay would also would be in the same position.